# Want to expand node with image on mouseover in D3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, d3.js

I'm trying to expand nodes on a mouseover event in D3.js but since I have attached images to the nodes the function seems to no longer work. It works perfectly without the image but I want it to expand both on mouseover and return it to normal when the mouse leaves the node again. Any suggestions on where I'm going wrong?

```
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
  .data(json.nodes)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .call(force.drag)
  .on('mouseover', connectedNodes)
  .on('mouseout', allNodes)
  .on('contextmenu', function(d) {
    d3.event.preventDefault();
    tip.show(d);
  }) //.on('mousedown', tip.show)
  .on('mouseleave', tip.hide);

node.append("circle")
  .attr("r", function(d) {
    return d.degree;
  })
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return color(d.group);
  })
  .on('mouseenter', function() {
    // select element in current context
    d3.select(this)
      .transition()
      .attr("r", function(d) {
        return d.degree + 10;
      });
  })
  // set back
  .on('mouseleave', function() {
    d3.select(this)
      .transition()
      .attr("r", function(d) {
        return d.degree;
      });
  });

node.append("clipPath")
  .attr("id", function(d, i) {
    return "node_clip" + i
  })
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", function(d) {
    return d.degree - 1;
  });

node.append("image")
  .attr("xlink:href", function(d) {
    return d.image;
  })
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return -d.degree
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return -d.degree
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return d.degree * 2
  })
  .attr("width", function(d) {
    return d.degree * 2
  })
  .attr("clip-path", function(d, i) {
    return "url(#node_clip" + i + ")"
  });
```

Comment: You are transitioning the circle but not the image or clippath.  In my comment to your last question, I suggested filling with a pattern.  This way it's a single circle filled with an image.  It's the correct way to do this.

Comment: Why don't you just select the image too when you mouse over so you change the sizes of both the circle and image ?

Comment: I tried that but to no avail.